# How long to flip over stage 1 of Falcon 9?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, entry-descent-landing, flipover

Curious how fast stage 1 flips over.

180 degrees is a lot of turning.

At a rate of 5 deg/s, it would take 36 seconds to flip. This seems very long for the maneuver.

A more modest duration of 10 s would mean a turning rate of 18 deg/s. This seems very fast for the maneuver.

Maybe somewhere in between?

Comment: The flip for the boostback? It has varied widely from launch to launch, and doesn't seem particularly constant in speed (being started with thrusters and completed using main engine thrust). It's also not exactly 180 degrees, and that also varies mission to mission.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherJamesHuff. Do you have a number for how long it might take? I'm just looking for a ballpark figure at this point. Just a number that has happened in any launch would be fine.

Comment: In order to better be able to answer this question, it would be good if you could document the extensive research you have done, what the results of that research were, why it didn't satisfactorily answer your question, which parts of the answers you did and did not understand, what you tried to understand the parts you didn't understand, and why that failed. That way, you prevent answerers wasting time repeating things you already know, or repeating things that you already found but didn't understand. It would also help optimizing the research of the answerers if they knew what didn'tT work.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: You're free to ignore the question if you feel you're wasting your time. It's not compulsory for you to answer. My hope is to learn small things like the timing of a Falcon 9 boostback burn while I struggle with bigger challenges, like powered explicit guidance. If I had the luxury of time to do extensive research on every question I have, I wouldn't be picking your brains here. And is it not perfectly clear from my question what I don't know? That is all you have to answer and that is all you should answer, if you choose to answer. Or you can just ignore like a free person can.

Comment: Perhaps spacex.com has a page or two which archive the flight path of a returning StageOne?  That should get you started.